# Proof of algebraic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have been trying to prove that this expression is true, but I don't think I have an adequate grasp of the rules of logarithmic expressions. Here is the expression:

$$a^{\log_b c} = c^{\log_b a}$$

I understand that $a^{\log_a b} = b$ (and vice versa), but I must be missing something.

Comment: While perhaps counterintuitive, I would take a logarithm on both sides to get rid of all exponents and get a product of logs which you can simplify using logarithm rules and basic algebra.

Comment: I think you want to write $a=b^{\log_ba}$ and $c=b^{\log_bc}$.

Comment: HINT: $r^s = b^{\log_b(r^s)} = b^{s\log_b(r)}$.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen like this? (On the left side) $a^{log_b c} = log_b c * log a$

Comment: @NatPorter that's the right idea, but not quite correct the way you wrote it. It's more like $a^{log_b c} = b^{\log_b(c) \log_b(a) }$. Do that to the other side ad well and use $\log_b(c) \log_b(a) = \log_b(a) \log_b(c)$

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand the algebra there... do you mind if I shoot you a private message?

Answer (score 4):

Two positive numbers are equal if and only if their logarithms (in the same base) are equal.

Compute the logarithm in base $b$ of both:

1. $\log_b(a^{\log_bc})=\log_b c\log_b a$
2. $\log_b(c^{\log_ba})=\dotsb$

Done.

Answer (score 2):

First Prove and convince yourself that for $x> 0; y > 0; n > 0; n \ne 1$ then $x = y \iff \log_n x = \log_n y$.

Pf: If $x = y$ then $f(x) = f(y)$ for all functions $f$ so $\log_n x = \log_n y$

And if $\log_n x = \log_n y = k$ then $n^k = x$... and $n^k = y$.  So $x = y$.

(For this to be acceptable it is *ESSENTIAL* that you  accept for all $n > 0$ and $n \ne 1$ and $x$ then there *does* exist a *unique* $k$ so that $n^k = x$.   That's actually not trivial and should not be taken as obvious but it is essential that this be shown and verified for the mere definition of logarithms to even make sense.)

.....

Okays so $a^{\log_b c} = c^{\log_b a} \iff \log_b (a^{\log_b c})  = \log_b (c^{\log_b a})$.

And $\log_b  (a^{\log_b c}) = \log_b c\log_b a$ (because $\log_n a^m = m\log_n a$).

And $\log_b (c^{\log_b a})=\log_b a\log_b c$

And that's that.

....

Another way of thinking about it is:

$a^{\log_b c} = (b^{\log_b a})^{\log_b c} = b^{\log_b a\cdot \log_b c}=(b^{\log_b c})^{\log_b a} = c^{\log_b a}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$a^{\log_bc}=a^{\frac{\log_ac}{\log_ab}}\\ = c^{\frac{1}{\log_ab}}\\=c^{\frac{1}{{\left(\frac{\log b}{\log a}\right)}}}\\=c^{\frac{\log a}{\log b}}\\=c^{\log_ba}$$

The key to the answer is based on the rule that $$\log_xy = \frac{\log_ky}{\log_kx}$$
This is the Change-of-Base Formula.